# Error in Unity/Visual Studio Code: The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on my first Unity project and I am following the Unity Roll a Ball minigame tutorial. I just created my C# code in Visual Studio Code for the CameraController to set up a camera that would follow the player (the ball) around, however, when I enter play mode the camera does not seem to be set up correctly and two errors pop up.

Error 1: The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!

Error 2: The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Main Camera') is missing!

I have the Main Camera in my Hierarchy so I am unsure why the program is telling me it is missing. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igilt.png)

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a script on the camera object that was renamed or deleted. Just right-click on the right side on the "(script)" part and select remove component. The warning should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

In your Inspector on the right of the editor, there is a component that is missing a script. A common reason of this is, you downloaded a package where the script is not included. To solve this problem, you can just right click on the component (Script) and select Remove Component. [How to Remove Component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7NXO.png). This should clear any warnings from the editor.